# Horizontal SubMenu

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'd like to create a horizontal sub-menu navigation bar that appears below the initial navigation bar when I hover above the appropriate menu item. I am not able to make the dropbown submenu appear horizontal, and after messing around with display:inline, both top-menu and sub-menu now appear jumbled together. I've posted my css below.

```
#nav{
 margin: 0 ; padding: 0;
 text-align: center;}
#nav li {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 display: inline;}
#nav li a{
 padding: 1em 2em;
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #F2583E ;
 font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
 font-size:1.25em;}


/*SubMenu*/
    #nav li ul{
     display: inline;
     position: relative;
     left: 0;
     padding: 0; margin:0 100;}
    #nav li:hover > ul{
    }
    #nav li ul li, #nav li ul li a{
     display: inline;}
    #nav li ul li{ 
     _display: inline; /* for IE5*/}
    #nav li ul li a{
      width: 150px;}
```

This is my html code.

```
   <body>              
 <div class="slide-down-page">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a class="active btn" href="home.html">Bio</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Writing</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Illustrations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
        </ul> 

    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
    </div>
        </body>
```

Comment: Can you share code via https://jsfiddle.net/? so can run it and can see actual issue?

Comment: After posting to jsfiddle, you can also post something similar in SO directly using the "Post HTML/CSS Code" button instead of "Post Code", and we can run the code live on SO.

Comment: Where is your `html` code?

Comment: I've added the html above. I also made a fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/q2sxnta3/ Cool tool! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please find the updated code below**, hope it will resolve your issue. let me know any further problem you face.

```css
#nav{
 margin: 0 ; padding: 0; position:fixed; width:100%; background:#e7e7e7}
#nav li {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-block; float:left}
#nav li a{
 padding:10px 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #F2583E ;
 font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
 font-size:1.25em; background:#e7e7e7;}
#nav li a:hover{background:#bababa;}
/*SubMenu*/
#nav li:hover ul{display:block;position:absolute; top:43px; width:100%; left:0px; background:#bababa;}
#nav li ul{
 display: none;}
#nav li:hover ul li, #nav li:hover ul li a{
 display: inline-block; float:left; padding:5px; background:#bababa}
#nav li ul li{ 
 _display: inline-block; /* for IE5*/}
#nav li ul li a{
  width: 150px;}
```

```html
   <body>              
 <div class="slide-down-page">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a class="active btn" href="home.html">Bio</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Writing</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Illustrations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
        </ul> 

    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
    </div>
        </body>
```

Comment: Is this what u were trying to do @tony

Comment: @toniitony: Please vote up and mark answer as appropriate solution if your issue has been solved through this. Thanks